# AFNetworking Submitting multi-part form not working?

Tags: ios, rest, afnetworking

So I'm testing out AFNetworking for a multipart form submission. I have my parameters set up, and for testing out NSData, I created a UIImage and convert that image to NSData. As you can imagine, I want the user to fill up and form, upload a picture, and have AFNetworking take care of sending my post request.

Somehow this isn't working? I'm getting a 400 Bad Request error.

Note: Assume I have my "path" parameter correct and the "params" are all set up properly.

```
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pekkle"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);

    // Setup path and parameters
    NSDictionary *params                    = @{
                                                @"description": description,
                                                @"title": title,
                                                @"userId": userId,
                                                @"collectionId": collectionId
                                                };

    // Setup manager and perform action
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager  = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    [manager POST:path parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFormData: imageData name:@"title"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
      NSLog(@"success");
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
NSLog(@"failure %@", error);
    }];
```

Here is the error

```
AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x8a9feb0> { URL: http://myurl.com/file? } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 624;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400)}
```

Comment: What does the error exactly says?

Comment: Try adding the corresponding mime type when uploading: `[formData appendPartWithFileData:photoImageData name:@"picture" fileName:@"file.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];`

Comment: @pacman321 I NSLoged the error and thats what it output. I believe I tried adding the mimeType before but it didn't work.

Comment: Why is your `content-type` `application/json`?  You're sending a binary file, not JSON.

Comment: The content-type should be `multipart/form-data`.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2